# Issue with Recursive Randomized pivot sort

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, pivot, quicksort

I'm having a bit of a problem writing a recursive function that sorts an array in java recursively . Right now it appears as though I have an infinite loop, and I can't seem to figure out where.

The primary function "rec_piv" searches from index1 to the pivot point and sorts the first half, then switches from the pivot point to the length of the array and sorts the second half. All of the comparisons are recorded by an int. [The array is of random size from 2 to 2014]

Thanks very much in advance!

```
public class Recursive_pivot {

    private Random random_size = new Random();
    private int size = random_size.nextInt(1024) + 2;
    public int[] a = new int[size];
    private Random elements = new Random();
    /* variable for rec_piv   */
    public int temp=0;
    public int temp2=0;
    private Random rand_pivot = new Random();
    private int pivot = rand_pivot.nextInt(size) + 2;
    private int first_half =a[0+1];
    private int second_half=a[pivot+1];
    private int first_index=0; //first half of the array
    private int second_index=pivot; //second half of the array
    //The pivot is randomly chosen.
    public int comparisons =0; //count the number of comparisons.

    public void fill(){
        for (int q=0; q<a.length; q++) {
            /* filling the array */
            a[q] = elements.nextInt(100 ) + 1;
        }
    }


    public void rec_piv(int first_index, int second_index) {
        if(first_index < pivot) {
            if(first_half > a[first_index]) {
                comparisons++;

                temp = a[first_index];
                a[first_index] = a[first_half];
                a[first_half] = temp;
            }

            rec_piv(first_index+1, second_index);
        }

        if(second_index < a.length) {
            if(second_half > a[second_index]) {
                comparisons++;

                temp2 = a[second_index];
                a[second_index] = a[second_half];
                a[second_half] = temp2;
            }
            rec_piv(first_index, second_index+1);
        }

    } //end of rec_piv

}//end of class.
```

Comment: You need to calculate the `pivot`, `first_half`, and `second_half` with every call to `rec_piv`.  Currently you are setting the pivot only once at the beginning, and it never changes.

Comment: Hi.  Asking people to spot errors in your code is not especially productive. You should use the debugger (or add print statements) to isolate the problem, by tracing the progress of your program, and comparing it to what you expect to happen. As soon as the two diverge, then you've found your problem. (And then if necessary, you should construct a [minimal test-case](http://sscce.org).)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to do a QSort here is a simple version of it.

```
public void quickSort(int array[], int start, int end)
{
    int i = start;                          // index of left-to-right scan
    int k = end;                            // index of right-to-left scan

    if (end - start >= 1)                   // check that there are at least two elements to sort
    {
            int pivot = array[start];       
            while (k > i)                   
            {
                while (array[i] <= pivot && i <= end && k > i)                            
                    i++;                                    
                while (array[k] > pivot && k >= start && k >= i) 
                    k--;                                        
                if (k > i)                                       
                    swap(array, i, k);                      
            }
            swap(array, start, k);                                                          
            quickSort(array, start, k - 1); // quicksort the left partition
            quickSort(array, k + 1, end);   // quicksort the right partition
    }
    else    // if there is only one element in the partition, do not do any sorting
    {
            return;                     // the array is sorted, so exit
    }
 }

 public void swap(int array[], int index1, int index2) 
 // pre: array is full and index1, index2 < array.length
// post: the values at indices 1 and 2 have been swapped
{
int temp = array[index1];           // store the first value in a temp
array[index1] = array[index2];      // copy the value of the second into the first
array[index2] = temp;               // copy the value of the temp into the second
}
```

from this site.
http://www.mycstutorials.com/articles/sorting/quicksort